# Passing an optional parameter in PHP Function

Tags: php

How can I pass an optional parameter to a PHP function. For example

```
function test($required, $optional){..}
```

So that i should be able to call the function by passing either one parameter or both. For example:

```
test($required, $optional)
test($required);
```

Thanks.

Comment: wow almost every single one of the answers for this question say the exact same thing. I don't know how you managed to pick one because they're all correct. :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

try this:

```
function test($required, $optional = NULL){..}
```

then you can call

```
test($required, $optional)
```

and with `$optional` null

```
test($required);
```

Comment: You mean when I pass `$required` AND '$optional' with values, this `$optional=NULL` would be overwritten? will work perfectly with the `$optinal` data?

Answer (score 11):

With a [default value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

```
function test($required, $optional="default value"){..}
```

Answer (score 8):

1) You can define default values for arguments like so:

```
function test($required, $optional = false) {}
```

2) You can use **func_num_args()** to get the number of arguments, **func_get_arg($n)** to get the n'th argument or **func_get_args()** to get an array of all arguments.

You can find a good summary here: [Function arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: +1 for mentioning another way

Comment: yes +1 for mentioning another way. It sure beats a repeat answer for an entire page.

Answer (score 6):

**You can also do this:**

```
function test($required, $optional = ''){
    #code
}
```

**when calling:**

```
test($required)
```

**or:**

```
test($required, $optional = 'something')
```

Comment: calling with `test($required, $optional = 'something')` is misleading, you're assigning `$optional` variable, not passing optional argument value by name

Comment: @McX does it work?

Comment: @Lemon It works with a side effect which if not well understood can lead to errors. For example someone may try to call `function f($a='', $b='')` with `f($b='b')` and think it will call `f('', 'b')` when it will actually call `f('b', '')` and set the global variable `$b='b'`

Comment: @McX that's a good point, but I guess it has more to do with being able to pay attention to the function you want to call. That can be solved by just adding 1 line of comment, preventing this unwanted side effect.

Answer (score 2):

just set the default parameters in your function ex.

```
function test($required, $optional = null, ... )
```

now you can call your function like this

```
test($required, $optional)
test($required);
```

Answer (score 0):

read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

dont pass any argument when decalare a function
like below

```
function myMin() {
      $list = func_get_args();
      $min = NULL;
      if (count($list)>0) $min = $list[0];
      for ($i=1; $i<count($list); $i++) {
         if ($min > $list[$i]) $min = $list[$i];
      }
      return $min;
   }

   print("\n Calling a function that uses func_get_args():\n");
   print("    ".myMin()."\n");
   print("    ".myMin(5)."\n");
   print("    ".myMin(5, 6, 2)."\n");
   print("    ".myMin(5, 6, 2, 9, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3)."\n");
?>
```